Nonlinear quadratic Schrödinger equation with variable coefficients
Consider the following quadratic Schrödinger equation in $Q_T = \Omega \times [0,T]$:
$$\begin{cases}
            i \partial_t u + \kappa(x,t) \Delta u + \beta(x,t) u^2 = f(x,t)\\
            u(x,0) = g(x)
           \end{cases}
        $$
where space $\Omega$ is assumed to be bounded, connected with smooth boundary. $\kappa (x,t)$ and $\beta (x,t)$ are smooth strictly positive, nonconstant parameters (hence bounded below/above by positive constants). $g,f$ are also smooth. I'm wondering if we could have any a-priori estimate on the solution $u$, for example, $$\vert \vert u \vert \vert _{W_2^{2,1}(Q_T)}\lesssim \vert\vert u \vert\vert_{W_2^{1,0}(Q_T)} + \vert \vert f \vert \vert _{L^2(Q_T)}$$
Since we have a parameter $\kappa$ before the Laplacian, usual technique like Duhamel's principle is not applicable. I also tried to follow the estimate methods in Elliptic & parabolic equations by Zhuoqun Wu (page 71-75), but mostly failed due to the imaginary number $i$ and the solution $u$ being complex (then we cannot directly square the solution to get $L^2$ norm, etc).

Have you done any research on the literature on variable coefficient Schrodinger equations? Even for the linear case, I expect you need some conditions on $\kappa$.

@MichaelRenardy To the best of my knowledge, less is known about this type of equation, especially $\kappa(x,t) \Delta u$ is not divergence form. Didn't even find any well-posedness results. But this equation has meanings in optics.
